# how to use pythontutor.com visualization in pycharm or visual studio IDE

Tags: debugging, plugins, pycharm, thonny, code-visualization

since im new in coding using a visual debuger is a big help for me to understand the codes im writing , using pythontutor.com or thonny app is very helpful as long as we do not import any external module .

some where i read to prevent the problem using pythontutor or thonny with imported module we can use pycharm ( which is IDE im using ) as a debugger that have potentioal visualizations exactly like pythontutor.com ( using plugin ) .

i couldnt find any plugin for that , my question is that how can i visualize my code in pycharm or visual studio for better understanding and debugging .

i need this visualizing function because i still struggle some times understanding the logic behind code, so visualizing will help me alot.

i searched pythontutor.com in plugin page but i couldnt find any thing.